# How to send link as body and store that as hyper link when we look at microsoft calendar window (small window without expanding)

Tags: calendar, microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-graph-calendar, python-o365

I am using below pease of code to create calendar event and event is getting created.

If i do single click over the event it is opening small popup window there we can see link as text where in bigger window if we expand then it is link.

small window

[image]

When you exapnd to bigger window by clicking on expand button.

[image]
Looking for solution to fix small window issue to show link as hyperlink.

Example code:

```
new_event = calendar.new_event()
new_event.subject = event["subject"]
new_event.start = dt.datetime.fromisoformat(event["start_datetime"])
new_event.end = dt.datetime.fromisoformat(event["end_datetime"])
meeting_link = event["meeting_link"]
new_event.body = f'Please click the below link to join the meeting. <a href="{meeting_link}">{meeting_link}</a>'
new_event.save()
```

Thanks

I have tried giving hyperlink.

```
new_event.body = f'Please click the below link to join the meeting. <a href="{meeting_link}">{meeting_link}</a>'
```